# NSTextfield Text disappears sometimes

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I'm working with two NSTextFields for Username and Password. Usually it works fine but occasionally when I switch out of the Username text field, the text in Username disappears, but the string value is still there. When I switch back to the Username text field, the text reappears, but disappears as soon as I click out or tab out. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Additionally, sometimes when I switch out of editing the Username text field, my program will lag. I don't know if the problems are related at all.

My program is an `NSTextFieldDelegate` and I implemented the `(BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor` function.

Comment: I realize when the text in the Username disappears. The program is running as a Menu Bar Item. About 2/3rds of the time when I close and then open the app again, then the Username texts disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I guess the problem was whenever I reopened the app, I would reinitialize the window. So I just made a `tempWindow` variable and that solved the problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but couldn't understand your solution. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: I don't exactly remember my solution, but I believe it was because I initialized a new window every time I opened the app. My solution, instead, was I think to just save a copy of my window instead of reinitializing it every time I opened to app. Is that a little clearer?